# 1990s or so fantasy book where a common girl falls in love with a prince and discovers she has magical gifts

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I vaguely remember it being written by a female Australian author and I believe it was published in the later 1990s or so. It was a trade paperback.

It starts with a young woman working in her family’s inn/tavern and then she gets swept up with a prince who later gets imprisoned and she frees him at the end. She travels to some place where he is getting ready for battle I think.

There is magic based on elemental powers. I remember that she has to work with elemental beings, and they start learning to work together.  At the end she ends up going to the castle where the prince is imprisoned and she frees him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall who or what the prince was imprisoned by? Also, do you remember any details about the cover?

Comment: The prince was imprisoned in his own castle. I don't remember by who. The cover was a classy trade paperback cover, not a typical fantasy cover, I want to say warm tones like gold or peach.

Comment: Leaving this as a comment, because it addresses a comment (cover description), not the question. The cover description and female Australian author leaves me with the impression that it is from the "Mystique Trilogy" by Traci Harding, probably book 1, "Gene of Isis". [Goodreads link](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2127283.Gene_Of_Isis) Although, that was published in 2006, not the 90's.

Comment: thanks, but that isn't it. This book takes place in a complete fantasy world, there is no portal from our world.

Comment: No problem, it was a long-shot to assume it was Traci Harding, which is why I left a comment only.

Comment: A few more details: This book is for adults, not ya. There is magic and the elemental creatures but no dragons or anything like that.
I think there was also an emphasis on singing/chanting to create the spells.